# 1С 8.3 (УПП): настройка обмена конфигурациями в РИБ

Tags: 1с

Добрый день. Такой вопрос - как настроить обмен данными в РИБ, чтобы передавалась только конфигурация при обмене? Есть настроенный обмен (по правилам обмена напрямую через подключение к информационной базе). Но при обмене передаются только данные, а конфигурация - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, в плане обмена можно просто снять автоматическую регистрацию всех объектов.

https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/2280/hdoc

Answer (score 0):

Конфигурация не передаётся. Обмен производится только информацией (Справочники, Документы, ...)

Comment: Вы не правы: https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/2280/hdoc

Comment: Каким образом переданная конфигурация .cf (грубо) может изменить другую базу (конфигурацию) и если на поддержке и версии сильно отличаются?

Comment: Ну вроде по ссылке всё расписано.